# Optimize SQL Query, need suggestions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server having 4 columns:

```
Invoice No, Date, Amt and ID
```

I have to find invoices that have same Invoice No, date and Amt but different ID.
I'm populating the results doing self join but seems like it's not the optimized way to fetch results.

My query:

```
select * from table t1 join 
table t2 on t1.invoice = t2.invoice 
where t1.invoice=t2.invoice and t1.amount=t2.amount and t1.date =t2.date and t1.id!=t2.id
```

Kindly suggest me an optimized way to fetch the correct result.

Comment: Hi @user9185088, it is not possible that you are using MySQL and QSLServer so please do edit that in your questions tags. Also, please do  share with us, in your question, the query you have already done ? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `group by InvoiceNumber, Date, Amount` ?

Comment: You are welcome You still have sql-server and mysql tag ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried group by but in output I only need invoice number not all records

Comment: But, @user9185088, we still do not know what DATABASE do you use ? Is it Oracle, MySQL , SQLServer or something else ? The code is not the same for this databases.

Comment: Database is SQLSERVER

Comment: Could you share the create script of the table and query execution plan so that we can suggest more realistic suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

try this. using left join and filter those nulls.

```
select * from (
    select t1.invoiceno, t1.date, t1.amt, t1.id, t2.id as t2ID
    from invoices t1
    left join invoices t2 on t2.invoiceno = t1.invoiceno 
        and t2.date = t1.date 
        and t2.amt = t1.amt
        and t2.id != t1.id) t3 
where coalesce(t3.t2ID, 0) != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use indexes to speed up the retrieving from large databases.
Use sub query but don't use a sub query just to show one column.

I advised to use sub query as new table to use joins.
just like the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select t1.* from table t1 
where not exists( select 1 form 
table t2 where t1.invoice = t2.invoice 
and t1.invoice=t2.invoice and t1.amount=t2.amount 
and t1.date =t2.date and   t1.id=t2.id
having count(*)>1
)
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul, thanks for replying but I'm not getting any records after using bthe query u mentioned

Comment: @user9185088 could you please share your tables data and expected output

Comment: @user9185088 i have edited my query and here is the demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=621899703139c2bd22e54c9dc9e52909

Answer (score 0):

> have to find invoices that have same Invoice No, date and Amt but different ID.

Use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.Invoice = t.invoice and
                    t2.Date = t.date and
                    t2.amount = t.amount and
                    t2.id <> t.id
             )
order by t.invoiceNo, t.date, t.amount, t.id;
```

This will show the matching invoices on adjacent rows.  For performance, you want an index on `(invoice, date, amount, id)`.

If you just want triplets where this occurs, you can use aggregation:

```
select invoice, date, amount, min(id), max(id)
from t
group by invoice, date, amount
having count(distinct id) > 1;
```

Note:  If there are more than two duplicates, this only shows two ids.